# Calculate Topographic wetness index in SAGA

Tags: saga, hydrology, topography, hydrography, topographic-wetness-index

i am currently working on a project which involves the quantification of the wetness in certain areas. However it produces quite different results from what i expected. I'll describe the steps i have taken.
To do so i used the ASTER global DEMv2 and clipped it to the parts to be examined. I have to clip the raster, because using the original DEM results in various errors saying "memory allocation failed".
[image: ASTER DEM]
Then i calculated the slope and Catchement area via the SAGA function Catchment Area (Mass-Flux-Method, parameter: flow-spit method area cell). I also tried the Parallel and recursive method, however the results are mostly the same.
Then i calculated the Topographic Wetness Index, but the results look very mixed (somewhere between a rainbow and random fuzzy bits) and values are always negative.
[image: example of the resulting TWI]
I expected that the resulting raster should look like and display index values like the following image in the pdf [PDF, page 14](http://saga-gis.org/geostat2011/05_saga_geomorphometry.pdf).

Has someone here experience with the quantification of topographic wetness in an area and could provide a tutorial how to do it right? 
I would appreciate using SAGA or QGIS, but i also have ArcGis 9 at Hand.

By the way:
If i just use the calculate the SAGA wetness index with the clipped elevation data above, SAGA always keeps crashing (i believe because of the large no-data areas, because smaller smarts work)

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot showing what data you chose when running Topographic Wetness Index? I suspect that you put wrong data as variables to the module.

Comment: i used the slope and the catchment area as calculated by parallel processing.

Comment: How many rows and cols do you have there? An alternative may be GRASS GIS which handles very large datasets, see http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.topidx.html

Comment: How many rows and cols do you have there? An alternative may be GRASS GIS which handles very large datasets, see http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.topidx.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to calculate at least the slope. F.ex I have the following data:
[image]

Then put the correct data as variables to the module:
[image]

And at last you should get the result:
[image]

**UPDATE**

With Catchment Area as input

[image]

the results are:

[image]

Comment: interesting and nice looking result. Why did you use the srtm elevation data as catchment area? I always used the catchment area as calculated by the various methods in SAGA

Comment: How did you calculate the catchment area? Which method (and maybe parameters) did you use?

Comment: module Catchment Area (Parallel) with only one input - Elevation: srtm.

Comment: Thank you for the post, Vladimir. Do you know the algorithm that saga uses to calculate catchment area? I would like to do this in ArcMap using the raster calculator, as ArcMap does not have a built in catchment area function.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for flowaccumliation. Here are directions for calculating CTI in the raster calculator that were posted on the ESRI forum. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/32896-from-DEM-to-CTI?highlight=CTI